# Finishing sentences with intransitive verb

Tags: grammar

Would you mind telling me the difference between these sentences?

1. I have no one to talk to.
2. I have no one to talk.
3. I haven't got anything to look at.
4. I haven't got anything to look.

Or number 2 and 4 are wrong? If wrong, then why?  please explain.

Comment: Numbers 2 and 4 are wrong.

Comment: Number 2 and 4 are indeed wrong. But it's not about "finishing sentences with intransitive verb". These are transitive verbs, with objects, but the objects have disappeared into the construction called the "relative infinitive". Notice they are all infinitives and they all modify noun phrases. This is a very special kind of construction that has very special grammar. 2 and 4 are wrong because they don't follow this special grammar.

Comment: As far as dictionaries are concerned "talk and look " both are the intransitive verb.How can these be transitive verbs?  And please discuss that special grammer?

Comment: @dz420 Not sure what dictionary you're using, the but [the ones I checked listed "talk" as a transitive verb](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/talk), as in "Debbie talked to Sally"

Comment: @Dan Bron In "Debbie talked to Sally", "Sally" is object of the preposition "to", not object of the verb "talk". A preposition phrase cannot be an object.

Comment: Agreed. "Debbie talked to Sally" is an example of its *intransitive* use.  Simply transitive examples include "Debbie talked turkey" or "Debbie talked nonsense".  Complexly transitive examples include "Debbie talked Sally into it".

Comment: The real issue here is whether the OP's examples 1) and 3) are infinitival relatives as JL asserts or simply 'hollow' clauses with the objects of the prepositions "to" and "at" missing but recoverable from antecedent expressions.

Comment: @paulM Could you explain it elaborately?

Comment: 2. I'm going to have to cancel the meeting. I have no one to talk. / 4. The wolf ignored what I was doing. So did the wolverine. And the brown bear, the grizzly, and the fox. I haven't got anything to look.

Comment: @dz420 I'd go with the 'relative clause' analysis. It's not too tricky to grasp - BillJ has explained it all in his answer

Answer (score 3):

[1] I have no one to talk to.

[3] I haven’t got anything to look at.

The infinitival clauses here are relative. They are dependents within an NP headed by a preceding noun where the relativized element is object of a stranded preposition Note that you can replace the infinitivals by finite relative clauses. Compare:

[1a] I have no one that I can talk to.

[3a] I haven’t got anything that I want to look at.

Note that "no one" and "anything" are the head nouns: they are heads of the NPs 1b – 3b below, where the infinitivals function as modifier:

[1b] no one to talk to

[3b] anything to look at

Your other two examples are incorrect since you can’t replace the infinitivals by finite relative clauses as I replaced the infinitival relatives in [1] and [3] by the finite ones in [1a] and [3a]. You can’t say *“I have no one that I can talk” and *“I haven’t got anything that I want to look”.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is what semantic role "no one" can play in relation to the infinitive.

> 1.   I have no one to talk to.

In this sentence, "to" is a stranded preposition in want of an object.   The lack is satisfied by "no one".   We can treat "talk to" as a phrasal verb, synonymous with "address".   The phrasal infinitive modifies "no one" and treats it as the semantic patient of its action.   Alternately, we can treat the stranded preposition as an anaphor, with "no one" as its antecedent.   Under this analysis, the patient is the recipient.

Regardless of whether "talk" stands as an intransitive with a modifier or as part of a transitive phrasal with an implied object, "no one" is transformed by the action of talking.

> 2.   I have no one to talk.

In this case, "talk" is not part of a phrasal verb and it is not modified by anything.   This intransitive verb neither requires nor implies an object.   The infinitive phrase still modifies the direct object of "have", but it does not allow for a semantic recipient, patient or theme.   What it does expect is an actor or agent.

"No one" does the talking.

I would like to consider an example that is not provided in the question:

> I have no one to talk to me.

Once again, "talk" is modified by a prepositional phrase.   This time, the preposition is not stranded.   "Me" acts as the explicit recipient or patient of "talk".   "No one" acts as its actor.   "I" is not involved, except that "I" and "me" share their referent.

> 3.   I haven't got anything to look at.

The analysis of 3 runs parallel to that of 1.   "At" is either stranded and anaphoric or it is part of a transitive phrasal verb.   In either case, "anything" is the semantic theme of the verb "look".

> 4.   I haven't got anything to look.

There is an additional complication in 4 that 2 lacks.   Much of the analysis does run parallel.   However, this verb expects its actor or agent to be a perceiver.   In other words, we expect the actor or agent to be conscious, with some capacity to think and to understand what it perceives.

"Anything" does not lend itself to this role.   The phrasing "anyone to look" is more sensible, since a person is a far more likely perceiver than an inanimate object.

In the comments above, FumbleFingers suggests that "anything" is better suited for such semantic roles as means or manner -- a tool used to look.   Such an expectation can be made explicit by prepositions like "with" and "through".

2 and 4 are not necessarily wrong.   They have different meanings than 1 and 3.   They have a more limited set of contexts in which they could make sense.   In the absence of context, they may seem awkward, confusing and unnatural.

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation. Could you consider these sentences

1) This song is worth listening to

2) This song is worth listening. 

any difference?

Comment: "I have no one to talk *to*" implies "I talk *to no one*".  "I haven't got anything to look *at*" implies "I don't look *at anything*".  "This song is worth listening *to*" implies "Listening *to this song* has worth".  All of those stranded prepositions have a function.  Offhand, I cannot imagine a context in which "This song is worth listening" makes sense.  "I have no one to talk" seems natural enough.  "I haven't got anything to look" seems unusual but possible.  "This song is worth listening" is completely beyond me.  I can't even begin an analysis.  Sorry.

Comment: The reason it works with _talk_ is because the sentence _someone talks_ makes sense. If you have _someone that talks_, you can have _someone to talk_. With listening, this doesn't work. A song doesn't listen, and I cannot _listen a song_, so a song cannot be worth listening.

Comment: You're not grasping the crucial point about the OP's examples 1) and 3) which is that _to talk to_ and _to look at_ are infinitival relative clauses.